# RDO Session - loop through entire Inbox and move emails

Tags: vba, outlook

Thanks to the excellent assistance given on this site I found the code below - which works perfectly.  I cannot (embarrassingly enough) figure out how to loop through the entire Inbox to move all emails (rather than selection as the code below does).

Any assistance most gratefully appreciated it.
John

```
Sub MoveWithRecDate()
' Moves selected emails with correct dates maintained

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Session As Redemption.RDOSession
Dim objRDOFolder As Redemption.RDOFolder
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objRDOMail As Redemption.RDOMail

Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.Logon
Set inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objRDOFolder = inbox.Parent.Folders("Cabinet")

For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
     Set objRDOMail = Session.GetMessageFromID(objItem.EntryID)
     objRDOMail.Move objRDOFolder
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had not heard of Redemption before reading your question.  It looks very interesting so thank you for the information; I will try it next time I need to write a new Outlook macro.

I assume from the lack of an answer to your question that few others use Redemption either.

The Redemption website implies that the structure of Redemption code will be almost identical to standard Outlook code.  I can only recall once writing a macro which operated on user selected items but my recollection is that the code looked like yours.  The code below is standard Outlook but I hope that is enough for you to create the equivalent Redemption code.

You macro has the comment `' Moves selected emails with correct dates maintained`.  This implies you think there is a method by which emails can be moved so that dates are not maintained.  I do not know such a method.

The code below examines every item in the Inbox.  I did not want to move everything out of my Inbox so I have skipped items that are not mail items and are not from a specific sender.

I hope this is enough to get you going.

```
Sub MoveWithRecDate()

  Dim FolderDest As MAPIFolder
  Dim ItemToBeMoved As Boolean
  Dim ItemCrnt As Object
  Dim FolderSrc As MAPIFolder

  Set FolderSrc = CreateObject("Outlook.Application"). _
              GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Set FolderDest = FolderSrc.Parent.Folders("Cabinet")

  For Each ItemCrnt In FolderSrc.Items
    ItemToBeMoved = True   ' Assume item to be moved until discover otherwise
    With ItemCrnt
      If .Class = olMail Then
        If .SenderEmailAddress <> "noreply@which.co.uk" Then
          ' Mail item not from Which
          ItemToBeMoved = False
        End If
      Else
        ' Not mail item so do not move
        ItemToBeMoved = False
      End If
      If ItemToBeMoved Then
        .Move FolderDest
      End If
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```